Need Help Customizing WSO2 Developer Portal: Understanding File Structure and Modifications
I'm working on customizing the WSO2 Developer Portal for a project, but I'm having trouble understanding the file structure and where I should make specific modifications. I'm relatively new to WSO2 and would greatly appreciate guidance from someone familiar with its architecture.
Here's what I need help with:
Understanding the purpose of key files: There are various files in the WSO2 Developer Portal (such as JavaScript, CSS, React components, etc.), and I'm unsure about their specific roles. Could anyone provide a brief overview of the main files or folders and their purposes?
Customizing the portal: I want to make changes to the UI, such as altering the header, modifying the layout, and adding custom branding. Where should I start, and which files should I be focusing on?
Best practices: Are there any best practices or common pitfalls I should be aware of when customizing the WSO2 Developer Portal? Any advice on maintaining compatibility with future updates?
Any pointers, documentation links, or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!
i looked in every file but i couldn't understand where should i make the modifications and for which one

Please refer to the below documentation to learn how to do the customizations to the WSO2 API Manager as per your requirements.
https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/customizations/customizing-the-developer-portal/overriding-developer-portal-theme/

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
